# Not able to use Kafka's JdbcSourceConnector to read data from Oracle DB to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to write a standalone java program using kafka-jdbc-connect API to stream data from oracle-table to kafka topic.

API used: I'm currently trying to use Kafka Connectors, JdbcSourceConnector class to be precise.

Constraint: Use Confluent Java API and not do it through CLI or by executing provided shell script.

What I did: create an instance of JdbcSourceConnector.java class and call start(Properties) method of this class by providing the Properties object as a parameter. This properties object has database connection properties, table whitelist property, topic prefix etc.

After starting thread, i'm unable to read the data from "topic-prefix-tablename" topic. I am not sure how to pass Kafka Broker details to JdbcSourceConnector. Calling start() method on JdbcSourceConnector starting thread but not doing anything.
Is there a simple java API tutorial page/example code i can refer because all the examples i see are using CLI/shell scripts?

Any help is appreciated

### Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> jdbcConnectorConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jdbcConnectorConfig.put(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.CONNECTION_URL_CONFIG, "<DATABASE_URL>");
        jdbcConnectorConfig.put(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.CONNECTION_USER_CONFIG, "<DATABASE_USER>");
        jdbcConnectorConfig.put(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.CONNECTION_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "<DATABASE_PASSWORD>");
        jdbcConnectorConfig.put(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "300000");
        jdbcConnectorConfig.put(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.BATCH_MAX_ROWS_CONFIG, "10");
        jdbcConnectorConfig.put(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.MODE_CONFIG, "timestamp");
        jdbcConnectorConfig.put(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.TABLE_WHITELIST_CONFIG, "<TABLE_NAME>");
        jdbcConnectorConfig.put(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_NAME_CONFIG, "<TABLE_COLUMN_NAME>");
        jdbcConnectorConfig.put(JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.TOPIC_PREFIX_CONFIG, "test-oracle-jdbc-");


        JdbcSourceConnector jdbcSourceConnector = new JdbcSourceConnector ();
        jdbcSourceConnector.start(jdbcConnectorConfig);

    }
```

Comment: Please share the code you have produced so far

Comment: Why are you trying to run this from your own program? Why not run it under Kafka Connect as it was intended? https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector

Comment: I have to load data from oracle to cassandra data store as a tactical solution. Even confluent-platform is available as a service with in our firm and has coast associated with it. We do not want to spent money for a tactical solution.

Comment: @Deepak You don't have to pay any license for Kafka Connect.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you are trying to do it in Standalone mode.**

In your Application run configuration, your main class should be "org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone" and you need to pass two property files as program arguments.

You should also extend "your-custom-JdbcSourceConnector" class with "org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceConnector" class

**Main Class:** org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone

**Program Arguments:** .\path-to-config\connect-standalone.conf  .\path-to-config\connetcor.properties

**"connect-standalone.conf"** file will contain all Kafka broker details.

```
// Example connect-standalone.conf
bootstrap.servers=<comma seperated brokers list here>

group.id=some_loca_group_id

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=connect.offset

offset.flush.interval.ms=100
offset.flush.timeout.ms=180000
buffer.memory=67108864
batch.size=128000
producers.acks=1
```

"**connector.properties**" file will contain all details required to create and start connector

```
// Example connector.properties
name=some-local-connector-name
connector.class=your-custom-JdbcSourceConnector    
tasks.max=3
topic=output-topic
fetchsize=10000
```

More info here : https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html#connector-example